# Help with SQL query - show today birthday on top of the table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008

I need to have the first results be people who's birthday is today, and the rest of the results sort by fname,lname

for example, i have this table:

```
fname|lname|Tdate
AA   |111  |03/08
BB   |222  |18/01
FF   |11   |20/01
CC   |333  |31/07
DD   |444  |10/04
EE   |22   |20/01
```

today = `20/01/2011`

and i need to see this:

```
fname|lname|Tdate
FF   |11   |20/01
EE   |22   |20/01
AA   |111  |03/08
BB   |222  |18/01
CC   |333  |31/07
DD   |444  |10/04
```

How to do it ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You're not making yourself very clear here..... do you want to display **today's** date?? Or what **birthday** do you want to show?? Not very clear... please clarify more!

Comment: What does "today birthday" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this at the end of your query.

```
order by 
case when cast(tdate as date) = cast(getdate() as date) THEN 1
else 0 end desc, 
fname, lname
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT FNAME, LNAME, TDATE ,1 AS RANK FROM  WHERE TDATE=GETDATE()

UNION

SELECT FNAME, LNAME, TDATE ,2 AS RANK FROM  WHERE TDATE<>GETDATE()

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY
    SIGN(ABS(DATEDIFF(day, Tdate, GETDATE()))),
    Tdate
```